# measure latency when sending TCP packets

Tags: networking, performance-testing, latency, throughput

I have two redhat 7 virtual machiens deployed in Azure.

I am looking for a tool which enable me to measure throughput, latency and jitter (min max and average),
when sending TCP and UDP packets from one vm to another.

I tried to use 'iperf3' but unfortunately, I do not get latancy and jitter results
when transmitting TCP packets:

[image]

Is there a way to get latancy and jitter results using 'iperf3' command,
or can you recommand other tool to use?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You may like to use [`mtr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_(software)), it measures round-trip latency to each hop in the path using ICMP, TCP or UDP. E.g.:

```
$ mtr --report-wide --show-ips --tcp --port 443 ya.ru
Start: 2020-10-14T13:13:26+0100
HOST: supernova                                       Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- 192.168.50.1                                     0.0%    10    0.7   0.7   0.7   0.8   0.0
  2.|-- 188.172.156.33.bcube.co.uk (188.172.156.33)      0.0%    10    3.1   5.0   3.1   8.8   2.2
  3.|-- 172.17.3.132                                     0.0%    10    2.0   2.3   2.0   2.7   0.2
  4.|-- 172.17.15.28                                     0.0%    10    2.3   4.7   2.0  16.5   4.6
  5.|-- 172.17.13.24                                     0.0%    10    3.3   3.7   2.9   6.4   1.1
  6.|-- ae0.mcs1.lhr11.uk.eth.zayo.com (64.125.29.184)   0.0%    10    5.2   2.6   1.9   5.2   1.1
  7.|-- ae-12.edge7.London1.Level3.net (4.68.70.65)      0.0%    10    2.2   2.5   1.9   3.4   0.6
  8.|-- ae-1-4.bar2.Helsinki1.Level3.net (4.69.162.142)  0.0%    10   38.6  39.3  38.5  43.7   1.6
  9.|-- 212.73.248.214                                   0.0%    10   38.9  38.9  38.7  39.2   0.2
 10.|-- ???                                             100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 11.|-- ya.ru (87.250.250.242)                           0.0%    10   36.4  36.5  36.1  38.1   0.6
```

Without `--report-wide` is runs in interactive mode.